Problem recovering public-key from signature using secp256k1 module
When i try to recover the pubklic key using :
const publicKey = signature.recoverPublicKey(message_hash);
It return a point
Point {
px: 19229884921856952681018566889643512244903203031630235368191033771919666945150n,
py: 101273832176960558837831690829023928168213252622890742797432854800419274346139n,
pz: 8657093880515198221050927670044834608546545230228381547077775722903846783459n
}
question : when i want to pass it to verify function using :
const verify_sender = ecp256k1.verify(signature,message_hash,publicKey);
it return publicKey must be hex string or Uint8Array?

From which library are you using recoverPublicKey function?

I use the 'ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1' library, but Thanks a lot i solved it by using the toHex() method at the end:
const sender = signature.recoverPublicKey(message_hash).toHex();
In general, the recoverPublicKey function has undergone significant changes. Now, you should extract it from the signature object instead of directly from the secp256k1 library.
For anyone struggling like I did to reconstruct the signature after sending it from the frontend, I used this code:
const signature = new secp256k1.Signature(BigInt(r), BigInt(s), recovery_Bit);
Thanks again, and hopefully this can help others.
